# data-pk attribute not showing in the x-editable CGridview

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, yii-extensions, x-editable

I am using x-editable to use inline editing in CGridview. http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php I am using postgresql as the database. The problem is that I am using functions in postgres to write queries and I am calling those functions from yii. The data provider I am using is CSqlDataprovider. So while using the inline edit the data-pk attribute is not showing in the grid view. So the update is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set keyField of dataProvider to 'id'.

```
dataProvider->keyField ='id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the PK has a param in your X-editable column:

```
$this->widget('editable.EditableField', array(
    'type'         => 'select',
    'model'        => $data,
    'attribute'    => 'user_status',
    'url'          => $this->createUrl('site/updateUser'),
    'pk'           => 'id',
    ));

?>
```

If you want more details, then provide us more information about your CgridView column and data that need to be saved.

[Source](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/widgets#Options)

Comment: It is not working.All the other pramateres except 'pk' is working. I tried with 'pk'=> '$data["id"]',

Comment: pk must be the name of the pk attribute. Post more code please